# "Trusted Add-in Catalogs" in the Trust Center settings of Outlook is missing on my system

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Microsoft Office Dev Center has an article called "Host an Office Add-in on Microsoft Azure". In step 4 of the section "Add the file share to the Trusted Add-ins catalog", they state that a shared folder needs to be added to the Trusted Add-in Catalogs.

The entry for "Trusted Add-in Catalogs" or "Trusted App Catalogs" is missing from the dialog on my system. I have Office Outlook 2019.

Here's the address for the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure#step-3-create-a-web-app-in-azure-using-the-azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting the documentation issue. Trusted Add-in Catalogs doesn’t apply to Outlook. We'll look into updating the documentation. We're tracking it internally with ID Office:8832709.

Comment: Is there any article that I can refer to Host an Outlook add-in, which is an ASP.NET 4.8 web app, on Azure?